# Calculating the side length of a hexagon

Tags: java, math, geometry

I have to make a method called getSideLength() for my AP Computer Science class. It calculates the formula of a hexagon using the following formula:

length = √(x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>+(y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>

This is the method that I was able to come up with:

```
public double getSideLength() {
/* To be implemented in part (a) */
Math.sqrt(x2-x1)Math.pow(2) + (y2-y1)Math.pow(2));
}
```

I am not really sure how to write that formula in java. Thanks

Comment: to make it easier for yourself, introduce some temporary variables e.g. xSq ySq and take note of how many parameters https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double) takes

Comment: @ScaryWombat ok but is the way that I wrote the formula is java correct

Comment: Use the `hypot` method of the `Math` class.  It does all the tricky stuff for you.

Comment: You should at a minimum know the syntax of Java; Otherwise, It would be us who do this homework.

Comment: If I were the professor, I'd _want_ the students to be familiar enough with the API to choose the _best_ way of doing something, instead of re-inventing a wheel.  Also, `hypot` can be more accurate than using a combination of `sqrt` and `pow`.

Comment: @DavidWallace AP Comp Sci is most likely their first class with programming and learning how to code the basics is definitely essential before using built in functions.

Comment: Doing it without built-in functions is far too hard for a beginner - you definitely need _either_ `hypot` or `sqrt`, unless you're going to do some extremely sophisticated stuff.  So if you're going to need one anyway, then why not pick the best one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the lack of parenthesis is causing issues with your order of operations. I would reccomend breaking it up into several steps to make the code more readable:

```
public double getSideLength(){
    double sideLength;
    double deltaX = x2 - x1;
    double deltaY = y2 - y1;
    double squaredSum = Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2);

    sideLength = Math.sqrt(squaredSum);

    return sideLength;

}
```

Note: I am not sure where you have defined `x1 x2 y1 y2`, but this answer assumes they are defined within the scope of this function. If you currently have them as global variables I would recommend changing them to local variables or parameters to the `getSideLength()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public double getSideLength(){

    return Math.hypot(x2-x1, y2-y1);
}
```